# WordPress have_posts() failure on search page - searchWP plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to create a loop which displays search results in *search.php* file.

I followed all of the instructions in the WordPress Codex tutorial located in here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

I have implemented the suggested code on my page like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is that the `else` condition fires (displaying *'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'*) suggesting that the `have_posts()` function failed.

**IMPORTANT:** I know that a lot of people in that situation suggest to use the `WP_Query` instance to get search results, and that does work, but the problem is I can't implement this suggestion. That's because I am also using a search enhancing plugin. It enhances relevance of search results and requires that **no** custom (`WP_Query`) calls are made, it allows only standard The Loop calls.

That is why I need to fix the problem with `have_posts()`.

**Could anybody suggest me what might be the cause of `have_posts()` execution failiure?**

**UPDATE:** As requested - I am adding the full page code below:

```
<?php

get_header(); 
    the_post(); 
?>

<?php define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); get_header(); ?>


    <div class="iecontent">
        <div class="g960">
            <div id="search">
                <div id="search-box">
                        <form action="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>" method="get">
                        <div>

                            <input type="text" name="s" value="<?php echo get_search_query()?>"  placeholder="Search..."/>
                            <input type="submit" name="searchsubmit" value="" class="submit"/>

                        </div>
                        </form>
                </div>
                 <div id="search-results">
                    <div class="search-result">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

                </div>
                </div>
                                <?php wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide full page code that you have implemented ?

Comment: It's not a failure. The query that is made by wordpress returns an empty array for the posts. So there aren't any post to mach your search criteria. Can you provide the full page code ?

Comment: Yes, I editted the question, the full page code is there now.

Comment: @Laxmana - I am tagging you in this comment just in case you don't get a notification about my reply, sometimes I have some problems with comment notifications, they do not show up in some situations.

Comment: Yes sometimes I have the same problem also.First of all two mistakes I noticed. You have two times the get_header(); and the function the_post(); outside the loop (3rd line). I would delete the the_post at 3rd line and the whole 4th line (the WP_USE_THEMES etc) to see if this will fix the problem. Just a try, not sure if this will fix it

Comment: @Laxmana - It still doesn't work, but what I noticed is the fact that page enumeration appears on the bottom when I input queries that would normally return a lot of results. This means that it is probably getting posts correctly, but it does not display them. Would you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: That's good. Now you are getting again the same message : 'Sorry no posts etc' ? Also inside the loop put : the_title(); As it is now even if you have results you will not see anything because you don't echo anything.

Comment: @Laxmana - Yes, I am getting the same message. After adding "the_title()" nothing changed, but it's inside the `if(have_posts())` so it won't be executed, because the `else` condition is still fireing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52395/discussion-between-laxmana-and-pe-ter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion we had on chat we came to conclusion that the plugin the OP uses (searchWP) alters the query and returns no posts.

When the OP disabled the plugin everything worked as expected.

Comment: If you find a solution to make it work with the plugin please post it.

Answer (score 1):

You have called get_header() twice and have called the_post() after header please remove it.

Best Regards,
Davit.